# javascript post to php for mysql insert record

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I have read many tutorials on this but just can't seem to get this to work - I have the following PHP file on the server:

```
<?php
    $host_name  = "";
    $database   = "";
    $user_name  = "";
    $password   = "";

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $sports = $_POST['sports'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE `userActivityLocation` WHERE user='$user' SET sports='$sports', location='$location'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I have tried several methods to no avail, not sure what Im doing wrong! Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

***EDIT***:
I have tried the following as suggested by morgunder but I still cant see any record being created in the database.

Here is the click listener for the submit button:

```
$('#register').click(function () {
        console.log("Ready! Getting the user details.");

        username = document.getElementById('login').value;
        password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        window.localStorage.setItem("user", username);
        console.log("Username: ", username);
        console.log("Password: ", password);
        console.log("E-Mail: ", email);

        var params, connection;

        params = {
            login: username,
            password: password,
            email: email
        };

        //console.log("Params: ", params);
        console.log("Creating new user");
        QB.users.create(params, function (err, result) {
            console.log("Result: ", result.toString());
            // callback function
            alert(username.toString());
            var usernamePost = username.toString();
            $.post("http://www.baseurl.co.uk/API/users.php", { user: usernamePost }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("HERE");
            });

            window.location = "sportsSelector.html"
        });
    });
```

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.  it may be easier to get it working in jQuery than straight JS.

Comment: Turn on error reporting as PHP would tell you what's wrong. You're mixing mysql and mysqli functions. You can't do that. Your code is also a security nightmare. as you are wide open to sql injections.

Comment: You don's specify what the problem is exactly, but by the look of it, you might be running into cross-domain problems. And you should use prepared statements when you insert in the database.

Comment: Thank you, i'm aware of the security issues, i am starting at the ground and working my way up, obviously this would not be production code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've said, that you want to **insert** record, but you use `UPDATE` SQL command. That's why the record isn't being created.

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `userActivityLocation`(user,sports,location) VALUES ('$user', '$sports', '$location')";
```

Also there are some thing to consider:

- jQuery is definitely easier, than plain old xhr object. And it handles cross-browser issues for you!
- If the API is on another server than the client you should set up some kind of cross origin filter on the server site (You can do it in `.htaccess` [like here](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)
- "Gluing" SQL from strings is not safe because of possible SQL injection. Prepared statements are the answer to that problem

Comment: Okay, fixed that, for a different php script targeting users, i have modified the code above^^

Comment: So I see... First thing you can do is to check out what comes back from server. In Firefox or Chrome open developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) and go to Network tab. Then click into your register button. See what's comming back. If you see OPTIONS request made from your client even though you're doing post it means that you have cross origin problems.

Comment: It works fine from the browser, but not from android. Thisn i really frustrating! Not a cross origin issue as i have now enabled cors via htaccess, this aspect is working fine. In android, via logcat i can see a status code 200 come back okay, but then i look at the db and theres nothing there. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Status 200 is not everything. When you'll have `Failed to connect to MySQL` error the status will also be 200. You have two options here. Either you connect to the server with debugger (I don't know how to do this with PHP) or you can add some additional logging into your php script that will tell you what works fine and what fails. Basically you can echo everything that matters. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidance! Will play with the php.

Comment: okay gathered more info on the issue using chrome's inspect feature over usb. The call now shows as 'cancelled' on the device, but works fine and creates the record in the db on the desktop browser

Comment: So does it work like it should or can I help with something else?

Comment: No, rather oddly the post is being 'cancelled' - can't say i've ever seen thi behaviour before without loss of networking. Very odd. The call is just failing altogether! Is my javascript all in order? The post to the qwuickblox backend works fine, but posting to my db doesnt. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! With help from you lovely people, but the final answer was an entirely separate less obvious issue. The event was firing, the post was starting, the server side code was good, the javascript was good after being fixed, but then it was being rudely interrupted by the window.location call! This is what was breaking the transaction.